# Onclick ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When I click on submit button info of textarea tag should be sent to mail using ajax.can anyone helpme.thankyou.

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit-btn", function() {
```

Comment: are you doing cross domain ajax call? is your web page also a part of `ivr.callxl.com`?

Comment: You have to prevent on submit button click default behaviour otherwise your form is submited

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you've hooked to the `click` event of the submit button, not the `submit` event of the `form`. This means that the form is still submit as normal, and the response from your AJAX request is ignored.

As mentioned, hook to the `submit` event of the `form` to solve the problem and use `preventDefault()` to stop the standard form submission:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#yourFormElement", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://ivr.callxl.com/callXLWeb/SendingEmail",
        type: 'POST',       
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { comment: $("#cmessage").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("successfully sent");
            } else {
                // handle error here...
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
            $("#errorResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that I removed the `async` property (as `true`) is the default, and provided an object to the `data` property so that the values are encoded for you.

You should also ensure that the domain you're calling supports cross domain requests, otherwise your request will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If that is the case, then you would need to make the request on the server-side.

Comment: can the issue be because of url? I am suspecting it is in different domain and it may a CORS issue

Comment: @user2181397 yes that is possibly an issue too. Added a note about it to the answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks. Need to pay attention, not having a good morning :)

Comment: @user2181397 Check your browser console for any error regarding cross domain request

Comment: @user2181397 I just checked and this server doesn't accept cross domain request, nor handling jsonp

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pf7c4Lv2/ this is the jsfiddle link i tried but it doesnt work.once check it please help me.thankyou.

Comment: Check the console you have an error, however as stated above you cannot make a request to this domain as it does not support CORS. You will need to make the request server side.

Comment: can you explain how to fix it

Comment: It's not a trivial task. See this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it like this.

```
$("#submit-btn").on("click",function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://ivr.callxl.com/callXLWeb/SendingEmail",
        type: 'POST',       
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { comment: $("#cmessage").val() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert("successfully sent");
            } else {
                // handle error here...
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
            $("#errorResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: first thing you have to change button type from "submit" to "button". <button type="button" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary pull-              right">Submit</button> .  After changing it when you click on submit button   you can check in you console there is a error showing something like this .    XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://ivr.callxl.com/callXLWeb/SendingEmail. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: so it it is because you are sending a request on a different domain . If you fix cross-site origin issue this code will work. Thanks